Generating OpenAPI with Eclipse Microprofile Annotations: How to configure global security scheme?
We generate OpenAPI files (openapi.json) from annotations in our Java code. Until now we were doing it with the Swagger annotations, but the Maven plugin we use (io.openapitools.swagger:swagger-maven-plugin) seems to be abandoned.
That's why we want to migrate to the Eclipse Microprofile annotations. Thankfully, there's also the corresponding SmallRye OpenAPI Maven Plugin.
However, with the old plugin we could specify a global security configuration:
          <swaggerConfig>
            <components>
              <securitySchemes>
                <basicAuth>
                  <description>Basic authentication</description>
                  <type>http</type>
                  <scheme>basic</scheme>
                  <in>header</in>
                </basicAuth>
              </securitySchemes>
            </components>
            <securityRequirements>
              <one>
                <entries>
                  <entry>
                    <name>basicAuth</name>
                  </entry>
                </entries>
              </one>
            </securityRequirements>
          </swaggerConfig>

This results in the following snippet in openapi.json:
"securitySchemes" : {
  "basicAuth" : {
    "type" : "http",
    "description" : "Basic authentication",
    "scheme" : "basic"
  }
}

I don't see this configuration the Smallrye plugin. I just see the SecurityScheme annotation, but annotating this on each and every endpoint seems like a lot of work when we secure all of our endpoints with basic authentication.
Is there a simple way to achieve security scheme configuration?
